# How to read hourly files of a day and merge it?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a folder of Netcdf files. These files are six hourly wind files for a month. I want to combine all the files. I don't know how to make a shell script to read the files in order of hour to combine them. Please help.

```
anal_00z20230118.nc
anal_00z20230119.nc
anal_00z20230120.nc
anal_00z20230121.nc
anal_00z20230122.nc
anal_00z20230123.nc
anal_00z20230124.nc
anal_00z20230125.nc
anal_00z20230126.nc
anal_00z20230127.nc
anal_00z20230128.nc
anal_00z20230129.nc
anal_00z20230130.nc
anal_00z20230131.nc
anal_06z20230118.nc
anal_06z20230119.nc
anal_06z20230120.nc
anal_06z20230121.nc
anal_06z20230122.nc
anal_06z20230123.nc
anal_06z20230124.nc
anal_06z20230125.nc
anal_06z20230126.nc
anal_06z20230127.nc
anal_06z20230128.nc
anal_06z20230129.nc
anal_06z20230130.nc
anal_12z20230118.nc
anal_12z20230119.nc
anal_12z20230120.nc
anal_12z20230121.nc
anal_12z20230122.nc
anal_12z20230123.nc
anal_12z20230124.nc
anal_12z20230125.nc
anal_12z20230126.nc
anal_12z20230127.nc
anal_12z20230128.nc
anal_12z20230129.nc
anal_12z20230130.nc
anal_18z20230118.nc
anal_18z20230119.nc
anal_18z20230120.nc
anal_18z20230121.nc
anal_18z20230122.nc
anal_18z20230123.nc
anal_18z20230124.nc
anal_18z20230125.nc
anal_18z20230126.nc
anal_18z20230127.nc
anal_18z20230128.nc
anal_18z20230129.nc
anal_18z20230130.nc
```

Comment: By 'combine' you meant 'concatenate'?

Comment: @GillesQuénot yes i want to merge the files like first anal_00z20230101 then anal_06z20230101 and so on till the end date into one single Netcdf file.

Comment: Do you want to combine month?

Comment: @GillesQuénot by hour. I want the output to be a 6 hourly wind file for the month of Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk and zsh:

```
set -o extendedglob
LC_ALL=C gawk '
  BEGINFILE {out = gensub(/(.*_)[0-9]{2}z/, "\\1", FILENAME) ".combined"}
  {print > out}' ./*_(00|06|12|18)z[0-9](#c8).nc
```

Would write a `anal_20230130.nc.combined` for each set of `anal_XXz20230130.nc` files.

In `bash`, the equivalent glob pattern would be `./*_@(00|06|12|18)z[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789].nc` for which you'd need `shopt -s extglob failglob`.

In both `bash` and `zsh`, globs are expanded in lexical order, so the `*_00z*` files will come before the `*_06z*` files themselves before the `*_12z*` ones themselves before the `*_18z*` ones.

If there's a very large number of files, you may run into `execve()` limit  on the size of arguments + environment and get a *"Argument list too long"* error.

That can be avoided by passing the list to zsh's builtin (so no execve() involved) `print -rNC1` to print it NUL-delimited to pass to `gawk`:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rNC1 ./*_(00|06|12|18)z[0-9](#c8).nc(N) |
  LC_ALL=C gawk '
    !start {ARGV[ARGC++] = $0; next}
    BEGINFILE {out = gensub(/(.*_)[0-9]{2}z/, "\\1", FILENAME) ".combined"}
    {print > out}' RS='\0' - start=1 RS='\n'
```

`bash` doesn't have `print -rNC1`, but you can emulate it with a function:

```
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
```

And use `nullglob` instead of `failglob` to get the equivalent of `zsh`'s `N` glob qualifier.

Note that if those 6-hourly files are split in the middle of a line (like if `anal_00z20230130.nc` ends in `unix.sta` not followed by a newline and `anal_06z20230130.nc` starts with `ckexchange.com`, the combined file will have `unix.sta<newline>ckexchange.com` instead of `unix.stackexchange.com`, as `gawk` will add a `ORS` after each record it reads even the non-delimited ones. If that's not what you want or if those files are not text files, you can change the `print` to `printf "%s", $0 RT`.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You should `close()` your file handle

Comment: @GillesQuénot, they're closed at the end, and `gawk` closes them as needed if it needs more file descriptors than the system limit allows, so that's not necessary.

Comment: Think of _re-usability_ with other implementations of `awk`

Comment: @GillesQuénot There's no reusability here,  `gensub()`, `BEGINFILE`, `RT` are all GNU extensions. Mingling with ARGV like that is also not  portable. So in any case it won't work with any other implementation.